# Android Layout is messed on Pixel and Nexus phones

Tags: android, xml

I am having this weird behaviour in the images below only on any Google phone, old or new, does not matter it just appears mistakenly. The sad thing is that it appears as expected on the rest of all phones. The annoying thing is that it appears correctly in the design as it appears in the image but everyone knows design never reflect reality in xml, the other annoying thing is that it is so simple, the root is the CoordinatorLayout and the text is just in the root :/

Here is the xml code

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout(This layout is the )
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:touchListener="@{0L}"
    >
    .
    .
    .
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a constraint layout, you should put `start`, `end` and `top` constraints for proper results.

Example code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout(This layout is the )
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:touchListener="@{0L}"
    >
    .
    .
    .
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"/>
```

Something like this in the proper format would work for you. Happy coding! :)

Comment: I tried that, I have tried even changing it to Relative layout, look it does not work @Akshat

Comment: @MohammadElsayed Try `Invalidate caches and restart` from Android Studio `File`